# Fill textbox with text from Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have looked at many answers on this topic but have found no solution because my particular situation uses a class called `Customer` and I am trying to set my textbox called `tbxFirstName` to the selected name I click on in the listbox by setting the `tbxFirstName.Text = cust.getFirstName;`.

I can not figure out why it is not re-filling the first name text box with the string in the selected item.

This is my code.

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxDatabase.Name = "CUSTOMERS";
    }

    private void btnAddCustomer_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);

        if (listBoxDatabase.Items.Contains(cust.ToString()))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Customer Already Exist!", "ERROR");
        } else
        {
            listBoxDatabase.Items.Add(cust.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void listBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);

        tbxFirstName.Text = cust.getFirstName;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Customer
{
    //Variables
    private string firstName, lastName, phone;

    //Constructor
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string phone)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public string getFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
    }

    public string getLastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    public string getPhone
    {
        get
        {
            return phone;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + phone;
    }
}
```

---

Can anyone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: Are you subscribing the methods to their respective events? If somewhere in the process listBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged was not added to the SelectedIndexChanged event on the list box the method would never get fired.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do when the listbox item is selected. You first create a customer with the first name from the tbxFirstName textbox and then you try to set that same value as tbxFirstName's Text property. **Edit:** Seems like Rahul was a few seconds ahead of me with answering.

Comment: @KelsonBall I believe it is subscribed to the actual object because i just double clicked the list box.

Comment: @hankide thank you for your help! Any idea as to how I would fix my issue? I left a comment below Rahul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are caused by the fact that you store a string in your ListBox items. Instead you should store a Customer instance and retrieve a Customer instance

Your Customer class contains the override of ToString, so the ListBox calls itself this override when it needs to display the item, but the underlying dataobject stored by the ListBox is a full Customer object

```
private void btnAddCustomer_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);

    // This will replace the Contains because now you have 
    // a collection of Customer not a collection of strings.
    if (listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>()
                       .Any(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString())) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Already Exist!", "ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
        // Add a customer, not its ToString representation
        listBoxDatabase.Items.Add(cust);
    }
}
```

Now, you can retrieve the Customer instance directly with

```
private void listBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (listBoxDatabase.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        Customer cust = listBoxDatabase.Items[listBoxDatabase.SelectedIndex] as Customer;
        tbxFirstName.Text = cust.getFirstName;
        tbxLastName.Text = cust.getLastName;
        tbxPhone.Text = cust.getPhone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Steve that was it! Gah now it makes sense. Before I actually did not even have a customer class because I have been making modifications to this and now I understand that the ToString() is not what I wanted. This worked perfectly and helped me very much. Thank you for the nice response and answer!

Comment: The issue now is that it it never triggers my error message if I try and add someone that is already in it. Any idea why Steve?

Comment: This is stuff for another question. Your Customer class needs to implement the IComparable interface. I will try to find an example

Comment: I understand. Thank you and I will try and figure it out or post another question

Comment: I don't like it too much but this seems to do the trick without going to the interface route: _if (listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>().Any(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString()))_

Comment: Once again it worked! I am not exactly sure if I understand what it is trying to do but it does work.

Comment: It uses the [IEnumerable<T> extensions methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx). The Cast<Customer> projects your items collection as an IEnumerable<Customer>, then the Any extension is applied to the IEnumerable<Customer> with a lambda expressions that convert each item in the list to a string (ToString) and tries to match the ToString from the newly created Customer instance. If any match is found all the statement returns with true

Comment: I see. I have tried this now with a potential removing of customer with a 'Delete' button and this approach does not seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: I believe it may not work because in my delete button method I do recreate a new cust customer and maybe it doesn't hold the objects?

Comment: Obviously this is a new question, which I will post about, but here is what will not work .    private void btnDelete_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Customer cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);

            if (listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>().Any(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString()))
            {

                listBoxDatabase.Items.Remove(cust);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Customer Found!", "ERROR");
            }
        }

Comment: _Customer custToDelete = listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString())); if(custToDelete != null) listBoxDatabase.Items.Remove(cust);_

Comment: I see what you are trying to do! However since I am not sure how to place it im not sure how to get it to work. I replaced the if statement in the btnADD (named it btnDELETE) and put in the code you just posted and nothing happens still

Comment: Please, post a new question with your code and with all the details.

Comment: I will. I apologize for the comments. Thank you for you help and advice. Ill post the new question link below.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not changing cause it's the same text as can be seen below. You are creating `Customer` object with data from `tbxFirstName.Text` and that's itself you are trying to re-populate in the same textbox.

```
    Customer cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);

    tbxFirstName.Text = cust.getFirstName;
```

Per your comment, you want to fill textbox with listbox selected item text. In that case you can just do like

```
private void listBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbxFirstName.Text = listBoxDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding; I am new. I am wanting to repopulate the same box. Meaning I only have 3 text boxes and I am wanting to enter text into the first name box and have it loaded into the list box (which it does just fine). But then I am wanting to, potentially, clear out all the fields and select the listbox customer and have it fill back in the respected fields. I do see what you are saying though so thank you!! You are right. I just have no idea how to fix this :/

Comment: So you want to fill textbox with listbox data ... right?

Comment: yes! But I have the data stored in the Customer class so i think that is causing me issues.

Comment: Rahul that dumps all of the item in the firstName field with the 'item' is actually a combination of first name, last name and phone number. I am just wanting the first name part of the selected item to be in the first name field. Ill post a screenshot to better help!

Answer (score 1):

From your original code posted you are creating a NEW customer each time the selection changes. But you want to be selecting the customer object that is highlighted in the listbox - not making a brand new one.

EDIT: I also noticed that when you add to the listbox you are adding a string, not the object. If you want to do it that way then you would need to parse the string and break it up by the spaces or something. I would suggest adding the item/object to the listbox instead

In your SelectedIndexChanged event try something like this

```
Customer c = (Customer)listboxDatabase.SelectedItem;
tbxFirstName.Text = c.FirstName;
tbxLastName.Text = c.LastName;
tbxPhoneNumber.Text = c.PhoneNumber;
```